# Creating a project from the terminal

Tags: android, terminal

I am experimenting with creating an Android project from the terminal and I have ran into an error, that I dont understand.
Using the Android development website I navigated to the android/tools directory and entered:

```
 android create project \    
 > target 2 \
 > name terminalTest \
 > path ./terminalTest \
 > activity terminalTestActivity \
```

But when I enter the next line:

```
> package com.android.terminalTest
```

I receive this error:

```
 Error: Argument 'com.android.terminalTest' is not recognized.
```

Compared to the information on the android development site:

```
  android create project \
  --target 1 \
  --name MyAndroidApp \
  --path ./MyAndroidAppProject \
  --activity MyAndroidAppActivity \
  --package com.example.myandroid
```

They look identical(except for the target of course), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: navigate to your `android-sdk/tools` directory first. The `android` binary should be there and get found then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't have the tools directory or the current directory in your path.  You could try ./android from the tools directory or jusr add it to your path.

Comment: Ok i added the android-sdks/tools to my path, but now im getting a new error...                android create project \
      > target 2 \
      > name terminalTest \
      > path ./terminalTestProject \
      > activity trminalTestActivity \
      > package com.android.terminalTest
      Error: Argument 'com.android.terminalTest' is not recognized.

Comment: Add in the -- at the beginning of each of the arguments.  Also the \ is not needed if you want to type it out on one line instead of multiple lines.  The following command worked for me `android create project --target 2 --name terminalTest --path ./terminalTestProjetc --activity trminalTestActivity --package com.android.terminalTest`

Comment: Thanks Rastaban.  It seemed that i was missing the two dashes and when i put everything on one line (avoiding the backslashes) it worked just fine.